# CSS Grid: Two column grid where left column items expands to content, right column items are fixed height

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

Using CSS grid, I am trying to create a grid where the height of the items on the left column are expandable with the content in them but the right hand column items are fixed height.

By defining rows, however, my fixed height item (Photo) on the right hand column is always contracting or expanding based on the content on the left

With minimal content, I want the Photo on the right to be fixed height somewhere between Summary and Stats1
[image]

With lots of content, I still want the Photo on the right to be fixed with summary on the left expanding

[image]

However, whenever I try to peg photo to a particular row, it ends up being the same height as the content of the row it's on like this

[image]

It seems to me that `grid-template-rows` stacks each row on top of the next. But I'm looking to define a row line that exists completely out of this stacking (470px from the top of the screen)

How would I achieve this?

My attempt. Notice how the Photo item is always expanding with the Statistics item

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0px 60px;
  grid-template-columns: 8fr 4fr;
  grid-gap: 18px;
  grid-template-rows:
    40px
    40px
    minmax(70px, max-content) /* at 70px, this line is above photo. at max content, it's lower */
    320px  /* with minimal content, this is where I want photo to be 40+40+70+320=470px */
    minmax(400px, max-content)
    minmax(400px, max-content)
}

.nav {
    background-color: #969593;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.name {
    background-color: #969593;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.photo {
    background-color: #969593;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.summary {
    background-color: #969593;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.stats1 {
    background-color: #969593;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.stats2 {
    background-color: #969593;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #969593;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">Nav</div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="photo">Photo</div>
  <div class="summary">
Summary
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quam lectus, ultricies et quam eu, venenatis viverra felis. Nullam pharetra efficitur lectus, sed eleifend tortor laoreet vel. Aliquam luctus porttitor dictum. Integer vel justo ligula. Suspendisse pellentesque, justo vel blandit aliquet, turpis lacus dictum lorem, sed mollis felis augue nec mi. Donec sed nulla dolor. Quisque eget dui sit amet libero scelerisque interdum eget ac enim. Fusce dolor mi, egestas id finibus non, scelerisque sit amet ante. Mauris scelerisque ut mi eget gravida. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam sodales dolor vel justo euismod vestibulum. Sed a metus facilisis, dictum turpis eget, vestibulum enim.
  </div>
  <div class="stats1">Stats1</div>
  <div class="stats2">Stats2</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please copy the (relevant) [mcve] code from your Codepen demo into the question itself, ideally as a working/running [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/82548), live demos elsewhere can be useful but, to guard against link-rot, we require the necessary code to be in your question.

Comment: *" I'm looking to define a row line that exists completely out of this stacking"* - That's not how CSS-Grid works.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use the grid to control the columns only, then use a flex box in each column to control the rows.

```css
.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

.d1>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.summary, .statistics, .photo, .sidebar {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.summary, .statistics {
  background: #eee;
}

.photo {
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 170px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    Column 1
    <div class="summary">summary</div>
    <div class="statistics">
      statistics 1
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="statistics">
      statistics 2
      <p>
        Cras volutpat velit non mi sagittis condimentum. Cras tempor aliquet turpis sed pretium. Nunc aliquet sodales turpis quis ultrices. Duis auctor accumsan enim, quis maximus ex malesuada a. Donec a felis ut erat tempus euismod non vel neque. Proin lectus massa, sagittis at imperdiet nec, consequat ut neque. Sed vel placerat neque, vel varius urna. Vivamus interdum euismod urna a accumsan. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Column 2
    <div class="photo">photo<br>fixed height</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar<br>fixed height</div>
  </div>
</div>
```